# Would PRC extend its Panda policy to Mars colonist?

Tags: politics, space-colonization, diplomacy

In the immediate future both the Chinese and its mascot population had surpassed every other countries by a staggering figure, however despite the introduction of genetic modified organic food which can be grown in days and consume little resources almost 62% of the entire human population are suffering from malnutrition. Fortunately joint venture between many countries to establish a healthy colony on Mars had already began and currently we have about two dozen Olympic swimming pool sized domes with state of the art facility to sustain the inhabitants.

Panda is considered a national treasure by the Chinese and these magnificent animals can play and sleep all day peacefully provided they are well fed otherwise the host nation will have to answer to the wrath of the dragon. The wildlife organization and other animal welfare groups support the adoption programme and willing to subsidize the cage and a padlock.

Why would Mars colonist wants to raise pandas and would PRC allow the first Panda in space?

I'm looking for a political motivation that prompt the largely conservative Chinese to expose their living national treasure to the unfamiliar and seemingly inhospitable world that the likelihood of the poor animal to die of both starvation and suffocation due to competition during blackout are quite high. This is also the crucial time when China had decided to break silence and come out of its den and it's could probably extend its panda policy to space and beyond.

Comment: How many people do you imagine fit in an Olympic swimming pool dome? Is there other accommodation for colonists or their flora? I'm confused by the question's assumptions on scale, I think.

Comment: @The Nate: in the immediate future and the Mars colonization just got started so no much settlers. Also we have not yet terraform the planet just think of it like when Columbus found America.

Comment: It sounds like food is the big issue. Spending trillions of dollars to put a hundred or so people on Mars isn't going to help that (probably the opposite). I get the question is *really* about pandas, but I don't believe we have sufficient information from you for this to be answerable in our format. In my opinion the question is too broad and/or would solicit idea generation. Pandas in space would be cute, though, so can you give us more context and acceptance criteria so we can come up with a "best" answer?

Comment: @type_outcast: working in progress!

Comment: I can imagine that China might push an artificial womb program to create new life on Mars (easier to safeguard sperm/eggs than live animals), and I would imagine that the Martian PRC delegates would see a Martian panda as a status symbol.

Answer (score 7):

#### Not yet, and perhaps never

Modern zoos are supposed to showcase wildlife without excessive harm to the animals. This is always a balance, but a dome on Mars is not suitable for a panda. How will the animal deal with the gravity? Will it like the food? Will it survive the transport *to* Mars or how is it raised there?

You talked about two dozen domes. How many people? 50? 100? 200? Whatever the answer, surely the panda will take at least as much effort/care as another person. A major city on Earth can afford that. A small village won't, and what you're talking about is a *very* small village.

Comment: I agree with this.  Although China could well ignore the ethical implications of transporting large animals to another planet, the rest of the world certainly wouldn't.  China might well be subject to widespread condemnation and accusations of animal cruelty for political gain.

Answer (score 5):

Political status. The Mars colonies are a joint venture, so presumably the PRC is part of the joint Mars colonization. Therefore, some of the Mars colonists are Chinese. The Chinese Martians and the PRC may well want to raise Pandas on the Red Planet as a symbol of their international, and now interplanetary, ascendancy.

Obviously, the PRC can supply the technical expertise at raising Pandas. Presumably, they will have done their research about adaptations to Martian conditions and know how to look after the animals housed in a Mars colony dome.